# pyroCMS: extending core (users) module

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Yes, I already read some posts in the official pyrocms forums about this issue.
So I have accepted that is no possible due CI architecture.

===

Said that. well, I MUST extend it ("users" module) at any cost because: The customer is always right, right? or wrong, what ever. I must do it.
So please advice about the best approach to accomplished. Hopefully considering pyroCMS upgrades in the future.

Really grateful for your time, Thanks.-

Comment: Hm... The last 3rd version of PyroCMS was built on top of Laravel, and not CodeIgniter. Are you talking about v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to do. Look at using [helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html). Or expand on your question.

Comment: Basically add more fields to their profiles, but add logic too, for example captcha test when login, confirmation emails when edit their profiles, etc... I want change the admin backend too: for example in the "manage users" page I need pagination and order_by support. Add/change user's photos, etc... THANKs!.-

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is going to be a way to get what you want and keep forward compatibility... You'll have to hack at the module--use helpers to minimize the code in the module--and re-evaluate when time to upgrade.

Comment: Sad but true. Well if I make a good job maybe upload the resulting code. Have you seeing a more powerful license than the Phil's [Don't be a Dick Public License](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/dbad-license)? Thanks.-

Comment: Maybe? Definitely! And please do use DBADPL--it's great! Best of luck.

Comment: True, thanks. And I must add that user admin have pagination only left add order_by support `->order_by('active', 'desc')`

Answer (score 2):

Extending PyroCMS user module feature is provided by PyroCMS system. For extending User moudle, this module have provided user libraries(ion_auth and user_lib) where we can call user modules functions such as

- activate / deactivate user
- change_password
- register user
- check group
- get users / Profiles
- remove user
- sending message to users

you can simply call the module like this:

```
        if ($id = $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $user_data_array))
        {
            echo 'success';
        }

        else
        {
            echo 'error';
        }
```

Comment: Helpful info, thanks. But I talk about extend the class. It's not possible. Only left improve it and put the enhancement available to the project, Why not?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a custom module which imports users's model, library and attach custom functions using events.php